# Uploading Image to Node.js express server Swift

Tags: node.js, swift, express, httprequest, multer

I am currently creating an app in which I will send an image from an iOS device to my expressjs server, using the multer middleware. I have the server side set up, yet I believe I have an error on the client side, because I cannot get my POST request to work correctly. Here is my swift code.

```
        class func changeChannelImage(handle: String, imageURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Int?, Error?) -> Void){
    let baseURL = "http://10.0.0.220:3000/channel/channelImage?handle=\(handle)"

    func createRequestBodyWith(parameters:[String:NSObject], boundary:String) -> Data{

        var body = Data()

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")

        var mimetype = "image/png"

        let defFileName = "channelImage.png"
        print(imageURL.absoluteString)
        do {
            var data = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL) //Image file URL in device's directory
            var image = UIImage(data: data)

            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)

            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"\(defFileName)\"\r\n")
            print("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
            body.append(imageData!)
            body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return body
    }
    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = createRequestBodyWith(parameters: [:], boundary: generateBoundaryString())


    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
                let res = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                let code = res.statusCode
                if code != 200 {
                    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(code, nil)
                }
        }
        else {
            print(error!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(0, error)
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the image file cannot be read properly by the server? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your image data into base64 String and then append it into body